# path of ActorRef changed in receivers end

Tags: akka, java-11

After creating the actor

```
actorRef.path().toString()
```

returns the path correctly akka://syst/user/ker/def

but when the same method called at the receivers end, $a or $c attached to the string as follows.

```
getSender().path().toString()
```

akka://syst/user/ker/def/$c

is this due to reboot of actor instance or due to any other reason?
How to keep the path in actorref unique?

Comment: Are you using the ask pattern by any chance?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "/$a" or "/$c" is indicating that you are receiving a child of the actor, rather than an actor itself. The additional "/" is indicating the child relationship. And the "$a" and "$c" are indicating that it's likely something autogenerated like a timer or (as Levi suggests) part of the `ask` pattern.

You'd have to provide a code example to understand why you are receiving the child rather than the parent.